# Не запускается Tomcat c war архивом, без war архива запускался

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, tomcat, java-8

Пытаюсь запустить java war архив на Tomcat удаленного сервера (на сервере установлен Linux Debian).

На удаленном сервере установил Tomcat. Тестовая страница Tomcat на порту 8080 загрузилась - все нормально было.

Далее через github залил в директорию Tomcat webapps (/opt/tomcat/webapps/) war архив (FastWater-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war).
Затем изменил файл конфигурации (/opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml) следующим образом, добавил в конце в какой папке нужно искать war, что его нужно авто раздеплоить и в какой папке искать проект:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />

  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>


  <Service name="Catalina">


    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">


      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <Context path="" docBase="water">
         <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
         <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
     </Context>

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Еще изменил файл /opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml, добавил пользователя администратора,остальных удалил:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="vladimir" password="vladrock" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

И после этого он перестал работать.
Запускается вроде успешно:

```
root@fast-water:~# /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat/
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat/
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat//temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat//bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat//bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

При проверки статуса выдает, что процесс shutdown.sh завершился провалом и главный процесс не запустился:

```
root@fast-water:/opt/tomcat/webapps# sudo systemctl status tomcat
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-04-25 13:22:51 UTC; 2s ago
  Process: 19306 ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 19282 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 19292 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 25 13:22:51 fast-water systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 25 13:22:51 fast-water systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 25 13:22:51 fast-water systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Пробую запустить данный процесс и получаю, что он ругается на порт, но этот порт со времени успешного запуска я не менял:

```
root@fast-water:~# /opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat/
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat/
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat//temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat//bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat//bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Apr 25, 2020 1:57:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Could not contact [localhost:8005] (base port [8005] and offset [0]). Tomcat may not be running.
Apr 25, 2020 1:57:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Error stopping Catalina
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:555)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:451)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:228)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:513)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:389)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:479)
```

В логах Cataline пишет, что не удалось запустить дочерний контейнер:

```
25-Apr-2020 11:50:21.943 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerB ase.startInternal A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionExcep tion: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleExcept ion: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.St andardRoot@51e2adc7]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.rep ort(FutureTask.java:122)


25-Apr-2020 11:49:52.909 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Apr-2020 11:49:52.921 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
25-Apr-2020 11:49:52.974 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Apr-2020 11:49:52.980 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.900 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.31
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.905 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 5 2020 19:32:12 UTC
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.905 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.31.0
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.905 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.905 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.9.0-9-amd64
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.905 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.906 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.906 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_241-b07
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.907 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.907 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.907 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.913 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat//conf/logging.properties
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.913 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.913 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.913 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.914 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.914 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.914 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat/
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.914 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat/
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.914 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat//temp
25-Apr-2020 11:50:20.914 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
25-Apr-2020 11:50:21.713 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Apr-2020 11:50:21.793 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [1,456] milliseconds
25-Apr-2020 11:50:21.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
25-Apr-2020 11:50:21.877 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
25-Apr-2020 11:50:21.943 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@51e2adc7]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@51e2adc7]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4800)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4935)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [/opt/tomcat/webapps/water] is not valid
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:709)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 30 more
25-Apr-2020 11:50:21.951 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
```

Comment: Может быть вы не в то место war файл кладёте? У меня по дефолту надо класть в `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps`. На это намекает (как я понимаю) вот это в логах: `The main resource set specified [/opt/tomcat/webapps/water] is not valid`

Comment: Вы правы, что-то не верно с /water
Tomcat я установил директорию:/opt/tomcat/
Папка /webapps у меня находится там же - /opt/tomcat/webapps/
Но вот папки /water там нет. Но я её указал в /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml.
В Доках, эта дир-ия, где Томкат буд искать прогу, в т.ч. WEB-INF/web.xml, если я правильно понял,то данные папки и файл появляются после деплоя war-ка?
Поэтому я решил, что если я укажу в /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml docBase="water",то Томкат мне раздеплоит мой war в данную папку,там появится после деплоя WEB-INF/web.xml.
Что-то я неверно понял,подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Я ни разу не правил дефолтные настройки Tomcat, так что не уверен что именно там за что отвечает. Но, возможно, вам поможет вот эта инофрмация: при дефолтных настройках я кладу war файл в webapps папку, после чего оно деплоится и в папке webapps появляется папка для war файла с имененем war файла. Там да, есть в т.ч. WEB-INF/web.xml. Т.е., возможно, вам надо убрать `water` папку из конфига.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло!